# Shared element transition with picasso not working even after implementing callback

Tags: java, android, picasso, shared-element-transition

The image moves perfectly the **first time** into its place i.e detail activity image view and also returns perfectly back to the main activity but when I click the same image **next time** the transition animation moves the image to an incorrect (too high) offset in the detail activity  and once the animation completes the image will appear to "warp" into the correct position.

Here is my DetailActivity.java file:

```
package com.akshitjain.popularmovies;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        postponeEnterTransition();
    }

    ImageView backdropImageView = (ImageView)       findViewById(R.id.detail_image_view);
    final ImageView posterImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_poster);
    TextView overviewTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.overview_text_view);
    TextView releaseDateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.release_date);
    TextView userRatingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_rating);
    TextView genreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.genre);
    genreTextView.setText("");
    Genre genreObject = new Genre();
    String genreName;

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Constants.MOVIE_OBJECT_PARCELABLE_EXTRA)) {
        Movies movies = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.MOVIE_OBJECT_PARCELABLE_EXTRA);
        int[] genre;
        genre = movies.genre;
        for (int i = 0; i < genre.length; ++i) {
            genreName = genreObject.getGenreName(genre[i]);
            genreTextView.append(genreName);
            if (i < genre.length - 1) {
                genreTextView.append(", ");
            }
        }

        setTitle(movies.originalTitle);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load((Constants.IMAGE_BASE_URL + Constants.POSTER_SIZE_LARGE).trim() + movies.backdropPath)
                .into(backdropImageView);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load((Constants.IMAGE_BASE_URL + Constants.POSTER_SIZE_SMALL).trim() + movies.posterPath)
                .into(posterImageView, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                posterImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
                                        new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                    posterImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                                                    startPostponedEnterTransition();
                                                }
                                                return true;
                                            }
                                        }

                                );
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                            }
                        }

                );
        overviewTextView.setText(movies.overview);
        releaseDateTextView.setText(movies.releaseDate);
        userRatingTextView.setText(movies.userRating);
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            supportFinishAfterTransition();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
posterImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load((Constants.IMAGE_BASE_URL + Constants.POSTER_SIZE_SMALL).trim() + movies.posterPath)
            .into(posterImageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                             startPostponedEnterTransition();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }
                    });
        }
}
```

Comment: sorry but i am still having the same problem.Is it something related to canvas opacity??

Comment: Could you post a video link